# sql query to get distinct records based on created date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image]

I have some records as in the image. I want to write a sql query to fetch the latest unique records so that I only have two records on the basis of UserAlertTicketID and latest Created Date. In this case the output would be like:

"CB23C56F-B067-415E-AD62-59DF4DA4F26D" "2" "2011-03-04 09:49:59.440" "9EDB3DBC-4685-414D-A48B-04CA8285A2D1"

"9FA4D72B-8BB3-4CE9-BCA2-C334AF47EB30" "3" "2011-03-04 09:05:46.817" "94C67A9C-3818-4AB5-A6F6-CD7BD69FAEC7"

Kindly Help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table GROUP BY UserAlertTicketID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

EDIT: this may not do what you want, however try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 T1.* FROM Table T1 LEFT JOIN Table T2 
ON (T1.AlertTicketEventID = T2.AlertTicketEventID AND T1.CreatedDate < T2.CreatedDate) 
WHERE T2.AlertTicketEventID IS NULL ORDER BY T1.CreatedDate DESC
```

This method will avoid using aggregates and should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the query. I got the result what I want. but will this work for number of records means more than that of records in my question? I suppose it will take only top 2 records?

Comment: Yes this will return only the last two, to return every last unique AlertTicketEventID record, simply remove the 'TOP 2' clause, or change to requirements e.g. TOP n

Comment: But I want the output on the basis of UserAlertTicketID and CreatedDate. If you see in the image, there are 2 records of "9EDB3DBC-4685-414D-A48B-04CA8285A2D1" and 3 records of "94C67A9C-3818-4AB5-A6F6-CD7BD69FAEC7". I want latest record from these 2 values?

Comment: @Tarun, If you remove the TOP 2 clause, it will return the latest Unique AlertTicketEventID records. So if you have more AlertTicketEventID's it will also return the latest one - i think you need to remove it reading the initial question again

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
a.AlertTicketEventId,
a.AlertTicketStatusID,
a.CreatedDate,
a.UserAlertTicketID 
FROM <Table> a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
     AlertTicketStatusID 
    ,MAX(CreatedDate) AS LastDate
FROM <Table>
GROUP BY AlertTicketStatusID
) b ON a.AlertTicketStatusID = b.AlertTicketStatusID AND a.CreatedDate = b.CreatedDate
```

Comment: @Hallie.Thanx for the reply. I tried the query but it returned the 3 records. Not the result as in my question. I want to only 2 records.